# Postgres C api functions with optional arguments

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I would like to create a function

```
 CREATE FUNCTION func(a INT, b DOUBLE PRECISION = 1e-9, c DOUBLE PRECISION = 1e-9)
     RETURNS BOOLEAN
    AS 'MODULE_PATHNAME'
    LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

How can one determine which arguments were actually passed to the C api?

Can one just use a check like

```
PG_GETARG_DATUM(1) != NULL
```

to check if the argument 1 was passed? I am writing the code for postgres >= 9.1

Comment: there are functions `PG_ARGISNULL(n), PG_NARGS()`

Comment: In your example `b` and `c` will always be actually passed, either with default or explicit values. PG_NARGS is only useful if several Postgres functions share the same C code